# Mesh Collider that detects transparency

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have lots of meshes for a 2D project that I place on quads (as a material to the quads). They're like "maps"; filled from the inside but have transparent edges.

I make a polygon collider for each map and place it on top of it so that I can use `Physics2D.Raycast()` to detect whether the user has placed an object on the map or off the map. They're like shapes (polygons).

The process of making the polygon collider is time-consuming and the quality isn't so good. Is there some Mesh collider that detects transparency and therefore shapes itself to the shape of the map? Or is there a way to make a script that shapes the collider to the shape of the map?

Comment: you could write a script that calculates the convex hull of the non-transparent pixels of your sprite to approximate the collider area. These points can be connected to form your polygon collider

Comment: Mina, did you solve this problem by any chance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that the `Polygon Collider 2D` has got a software feature to generate a polygon to such a transparent mesh. One only needs to drag and drop a sprite on the polygon collider component.

Comment: he said he has quads, not sprites. He's working in 3d.

Comment: This saved my bacon! I was headed down a rabbit hole of trying to draw handles at every point to allow for a click and drag mechanic! Glad this feature exists!

Comment: But how to do it on the fly with a programmatically generated image?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution: use RaycastAll to retrieve all the objects hit, then return the closest object such that the alpha value of the pixel is not 0.

```
private static RaycastHit? RaycastWithTransparency(Ray ray)
{

    var res = Physics.RaycastAll(ray, float.MaxValue).ToList().OrderBy(h => h.distance);


    foreach (var h in res)
    {
        var col = h.collider;


        Renderer rend = h.transform.GetComponent<Renderer>();
        Texture2D tex = rend.material.mainTexture as Texture2D;
        var xInTex = (int) (h.textureCoord.x*tex.width);
        var yInTex = (int) (h.textureCoord.y*tex.height);
        var pix = tex.GetPixel(xInTex, yInTex);

        if (pix.a > 0)
        {
            //Debug.Log("You hit: " + col.name + " position " + h.textureCoord.x + " , " + h.textureCoord.y);
            return h;

        }
    }
    return null;
}
```